# On New or Update Sftp connector issue with pipe closed

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am using On New or Update sftp connector to read around 3000+ files daily. Everything runs smooth. However,at the end of processing phase. the sftp connector throws below error,and does not process the last file which remains in the sftp folder for next run. this error scenario keeps repeating for each run. Hence, the last file of each run does not process.

```
20:03:37.733     06/15/2022     Worker-0     [MuleRuntime].uber.33: [demo-data-api].prcsFiles-Error-SuccessFlow.CPU_INTENSIVE @38f99b06     ERROR
event:c3ccc560-f1be-11ec-a890-02732233ad66
********************************************************************************
Message               : "org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.ReaderParsingException: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException - Exception was found trying to retrieve the contents of file /home/transaction/data.json
org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Exception was found trying to retrieve the contents of file /home/transaction/data.json

at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:427)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.exception(SftpClient.java:423)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getFileContent(SftpClient.java:349)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpFileSystem.retrieveFileContent(SftpFileSystem.java:117)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.SftpInputStream$SftpFileInputStreamSupplier.getContentInputStream(SftpInputStream.java:111)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.SftpInputStream$SftpFileInputStreamSupplier.getContentInputStream(SftpInputStream.java:93)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractConnectedFileInputStreamSupplier.getContentInputStream(AbstractConnectedFileInputStreamSupplier.java:81)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileInputStreamSupplier.get(AbstractFileInputStreamSupplier.java:65)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileInputStreamSupplier.get(AbstractFileInputStreamSupplier.java:33)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.stream.LazyStreamSupplier.lambda$new$1(LazyStreamSupplier.java:29)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.stream.LazyStreamSupplier.get(LazyStreamSupplier.java:42)
    at org.mule.extension.file.common.api.stream.AbstractNonFinalizableFileInputStream.lambda$createLazyStream$0(AbstractNonFinalizableFileInputStream.java:48)
    at $java.io.InputStream$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$55e4687e.read(<generated>)
    at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:102)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.AbstractInputStreamBuffer.consumeStream(AbstractInputStreamBuffer.java:111)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.consumeForwardData(FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.java:239)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.consumeForwardData(FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.java:202)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.doGet(FileStoreInputStreamBuffer.java:125)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.AbstractInputStreamBuffer.get(AbstractInputStreamBuffer.java:93)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.BufferedCursorStream.assureDataInLocalBuffer(BufferedCursorStream.java:126)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.BufferedCursorStream.doRead(BufferedCursorStream.java:101)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.AbstractCursorStream.read(AbstractCursorStream.java:124)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.BufferedCursorStream.read(BufferedCursorStream.java:26)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.ManagedCursorStreamDecorator.read(ManagedCursorStreamDecorator.java:96)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.SeekableCursorStream.read(MuleTypedValue.scala:306)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.UTF8StreamSourceReader.handleBOM(SeekableStreamSourceReader.scala:179)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.UTF8StreamSourceReader.readAscii(SeekableStreamSourceReader.scala:163)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.JsonTokenizer.$init$(JsonTokenizer.scala:21)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.indexed.IndexedJsonTokenizer.<init>(IndexedJsonTokenizer.scala:15)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.indexed.IndexedJsonParser.parser(IndexedJsonParser.scala:17)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.JsonReader.readValue(JsonReader.scala:40)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.JsonReader.doRead(JsonReader.scala:30)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read(Reader.scala:35)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.reader.Reader.read$(Reader.scala:33)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.module.json.reader.JsonReader.read(JsonReader.scala:20)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.value(MuleTypedValue.scala:147)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType(DelegateValue.scala:17)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.valueType$(DelegateValue.scala:16)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleTypedValue.valueType(MuleTypedValue.scala:177)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.model.types.ObjectType$.accepts(Type.scala:1068)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.executors.BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.executeBinary(BinaryOverloadedStaticExecutor.scala:45)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ChainedBinaryOpNode.doExecute(ChainedBinaryOpNode.scala:37)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ChainedBinaryOpNode.execute(ChainedBinaryOpNode.scala:7)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.NullSafeNode.doExecute(NullSafeNode.scala:14)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.NullSafeNode.execute(NullSafeNode.scala:8)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.BinaryOpNode.doExecute(BinaryOpNode.scala:15)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.BinaryOpNode.execute(BinaryOpNode.scala:9)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.doExecute(DocumentNode.scala:26)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute(ValueNode.scala:26)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.ValueNode.execute$(ValueNode.scala:21)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.node.structure.DocumentNode.execute(DocumentNode.scala:11)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.interpreted.InterpretedMappingExecutableWeave.execute(InterpreterMappingCompilerPhase.scala:196)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:250)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.$anonfun$evaluate$2(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:101)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.doEvaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:285)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:100)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:274)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:51)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluateBoolean(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:72)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ProcessorExpressionRoute.accepts(ProcessorExpressionRoute.java:34)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ExecutableRoute.shouldExecute(ExecutableRoute.java:41)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ChoiceRouter$SinkRouter.lambda$route$0(ChoiceRouter.java:161)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ChoiceRouter$SinkRouter.route(ChoiceRouter.java:161)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedConsumer.accept(CheckedConsumer.java:19)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.rx.Exceptions.lambda$checkedConsumer$0(Exceptions.java:51)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:482)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:490)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:485)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:490)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:485)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:180)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:490)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:485)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:447)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:534)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:151)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException: Error occurred while trying to connect to host
    ... 112 more
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.api.SftpConnectionException.<init>(SftpConnectionException.java:38)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: 
    ... 112 more
Caused by: 4: 
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1540)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1290)
    at org.mule.extension.sftp.internal.connection.SftpClient.getFileContent(SftpClient.java:347)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel$MyPipedInputStream.updateReadSide(Channel.java:362)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1311)
    ... 112 mor, while reading `comingData` as Json.
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)

    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.utils.ExceptionHandler$.handleLocatableException(ExceptionHandler.scala:24)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.doEvaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:291)
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.evaluate(WeaveExpressionLanguageSession.scala:100)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.dataweave.DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor$1.evaluate(DataWeaveExpressionLanguageAdaptor.java:274)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluate(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:51)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.el.DefaultExpressionManagerSession.evaluateBoolean(DefaultExpressionManagerSession.java:72)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ProcessorExpressionRoute.accepts(ProcessorExpressionRoute.java:34)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.routing.ExecutableRou... [truncated]
```

SFTP Configuration:

```
<sftp:config name="SFTP_Config" doc:name="SFTP Config" doc:id="81f37ff8-d629-4f64-ab2c-5632350b8fca" >
 <sftp:connection host="sample.com" port="00" username="example1" password="111111" connectionTimeout="30" responseTimeout="30">
  <pooling-profile maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10" evictionCheckIntervalMillis="60000" minEvictionMillis="120000"/>
 </sftp:connection>

</sftp:config>

<flow name="prcsFiles" doc:id="55ac597a-378f-40b6-8041-df7ca8254ebe" maxConcurrency="1">
 <sftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="9a5d6eae-0fc6-46a5-be10-de98fb7ee16a" config-ref="SFTP_Config" directory="home/transaction/" outputMimeType="application/json" timeBetweenSizeCheckUnit="MILLISECONDS">
  <reconnect-forever/>
  <scheduling-strategy >
   <cron expression="0 15 10 ? * *" timeZone="UTC" />
  </scheduling-strategy>
 </sftp:listener>
</flow>
```

I am using cron expressing which runs once daily. does someone came across this issue before.
Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your connector configuration and XML of operation?

Comment: @Bansal see above used confirguration

Comment: Thanks. Can you update it in the question itself? Also, can you confirm if it is always a single file that remains or you can see that sometimes more files remain pending?

Comment: What is the exact version of the SFTP connector used by the application? And is the error complete? Seems that the exact error is missing. It is sometimes Ok to skip over a long stacktrace but the rest of the error lines should be shown in the question. Otherwise we miss valuable troubleshooting information.

Comment: @Bansal updated the question. it is always last single file that remains in sftp for next run. then same happens again in the second run. i thikn it is sth in reconnection to the sftp. maybe i'm missing sth there

Comment: @aled Im using the version 1.4.1. i ve pasted the whole error for ur reference

Comment: Is there no `Error type:` line in the log?

Comment: @aled this is  the exact error i got. I copied the whole error as shown above

Comment: Ok, I was wondering because usually there is some more detail, but in some situations like this that is missing.